# Why doesn't my Android view not stay at the bottom when EditText is selected?

Tags: android, android-edittext, positioning, android-relativelayout

I have a layout where I have a button bar where:

```
layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

I have a `RelativeLayout` on top of that which contains an EditText and an ImageButton.

When I select the EditText to edit it, the `com.test.OkCancelBar` goes up right below the edit text and in some cases shrinks the height of the EditText. The EditText IS positioned dynamically so I'm not sure if that affects anything.

How can I prevent the `com.test.OkCancelBar` from doing this, in other words, force it to stay at the bottom of my app at all times?

OkCancelBar.java:

```
public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    setWeightSum(1.0f);
}
```

mylayout.xml:

```
<com.test.OkCancelBar
    android:id="@+id/footerbar_lists"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/footer_bkgrnd"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_list_item_edit">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_list_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_btn_save_list"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_list_edit_text"
        android:src="@drawable/search">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried setting gravity to bottom inside OkCancelBar.java and explicitly setting the height in the xml:

```
public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        setWeightSum(1.0f); 

<com.test.OkCancelBar
            android:id="@+id/footerbar_lists"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="55dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_bkgrnd"/>
```

Comment: Is this the complete xml layout for this view? Because I don't see any button that has the attribute 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"' in it

Comment: Alex:  com.test.OkCancelBar is an inflatable class that contains my buttons when inflated and it has "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" as you can see above.

Comment: Not sure this would work, but I would try setting the layout_height of the RelativeLayout to fill_parent. Although I don't know why it's working at all if you have it set to wrap_content, as then the layout wouldn't cover the entire screen.

Comment: I think u should put com.test.OkCancelBar after the RelativeLayout in ur XML file.

Comment: @Alex which RelativeLayout are you referring to?

Comment: The one you have posted. Are you saying that there is another relative layout containing the above relative layout and your button bar? If so, could you post that code too?

Comment: Alex, no more Relative Layouts. Your suggestion did not work though, but thx. Also the OkCancelBar class is a LinearLayout so I'm wondering if that makes a difference?

Comment: Also I just noticed that, if you rotate the phone to landscape mode the footer bar stays put , hmmmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by setting the windowSoftInputMode for my activity in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name="List" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
```